# Pausing a registration

Tags: cognito-forms

I published a link that isn't supposed to be live for two more weeks.

Is there a way to pause registration?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent people from accessing your form before a specific date, you can set availability dates from the Form Settings menu. Check out this help topic for more information: https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/17/building-forms/form-settings#form-availability